# Rails 3 and devise, devise logging out when there are errors on user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I'm using devise for a site and it seem to be acting strangely.

I have a database boolean column on the user that stores preferences, lets call it show_help .

However in the view when logged in, if I call current_user.show_help , it throws an erros saying there is no such method. I'm using current_user in other view for devise things such as current_user.email .

What stranger still is when this error is caused it logs out the current user and then you cannot log back in with out restarting the server.

I was wondering if anyone else knew what the problem was?

Comment: The method is actually called show_help, right?  Please post the user section of  db/schema.rb

Comment: Yeah the schema was out of wack. I was upgrading from authlogic so it must have happened in that process. Pop it as an answer and I'll give you an tick. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there is an issue with your database.  Try the following:

- Check the user section of your db/schema.rb
- run rake db:migrate